# Checkbox validation with Yup and Formik isn't working

Tags: javascript, validation, material-ui, formik, yup

I'm not sure, why the validation isn't working:

```
export default function Check() {
  const label = { inputProps: { "aria-label": "termsOfService" } };

  const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
    termsOfService: yup
      .boolean()
      .oneOf([true], "Required.")
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      termsOfService: false,
    },
    validationSchema: formSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      //logic
    },
  });

  return (
    <Checkbox
        {...label}
        name="termsOfService"
        id="termsOfService"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        error={
          formik.touched.termsOfService &&
          Boolean(formik.errors.termsOfService)
         }
        value={formik.values.termsOfService}
        helperText={formik.touched.termsOfService && formik.errors.termsOfService}
     />
}
```

The error "Required" doesn't show up, if the Checkbox is unchecked.  In my console I'm getting the following error:

"Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `error`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: error="false" or error={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with error={condition && value}, pass error={condition ? value : undefined} instead."

So I've been trying to play around with:

```
       error={
          formik.touched.termsOfService &&
          Boolean(formik.errors.termsOfService)
       }
```

But nothing worked so far. Btw, I'm using Next.js. And if the Checkbox is checked everything works fine..

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

error is not a boolean , and you try to give him a boolean.
try instead of Boolean(...) => formik.errors.termsOfService, delete the Boolean function.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying this solution as well. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).